# How to hide text box while taking print in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

While taking pring textbox also coming in print page and its look like bad UI. how can i remove that textbox and show only the text entered value.

[image]

Please find the image. How can I resolve this issue. I want to show only the text what I have entered in the textbox. Please help me how can I resolve this issue.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ttLueng/166)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function PrintDiv() {
            var contents = document.getElementById("dvContents").innerHTML;
            var frame1 = document.createElement('iframe');
            frame1.name = "frame1";
            frame1.style.position = "absolute";
            frame1.style.top = "-1000000px";
            document.body.appendChild(frame1);
            var frameDoc = frame1.contentWindow ? frame1.contentWindow : frame1.contentDocument.document ? frame1.contentDocument.document : frame1.contentDocument;
            frameDoc.document.open();
            frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
            frameDoc.document.write('</head><body>');
            frameDoc.document.write(contents);
            frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
            frameDoc.document.close();
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.frames["frame1"].focus();
                window.frames["frame1"].print();
                document.body.removeChild(frame1);
            }, 500);
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">
    <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial">ASPSnippets.com
        Sample page</span>
    <hr />
    <div id="dvContents" style="border: 1px dotted black; padding: 5px; width: 300px">
        <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial">Hello,
            <br />
            This is <span style="color: #18B5F0">Mudassar Khan</span>.<br />
            Hoping that you are enjoying my articles!</span>
            <input type="text" class="input printText" value="test">
    </div>
    <br />
    <input type="button" onclick="PrintDiv();" value="Print" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: `.input {border: none}` || `@media print {.input {border: none}}`

Answer (score 1):

please add some class to wanted input `.printText`:

```
<td width="267">Policy <br/>Number:  <input type="text" class="input printText" size="30"></td>
```

**in css hide the border of input**

```
@media print
{
    #non-printable { display: none!important; }
    #printable { display: block; }
    .printText{border:none!important;}
}
```

Comment: The !important is not really necessary.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9ttLueng/166/ Please check this link. I tried this. But its not working in this format.

Comment: The above your code is working for the old scenario. Please check the above fiddle. Its not working for this. Could you please help me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom class to that `input`, let's say `print-hidden` and Apply `css` to it using `@media` like this

```
@media print {
  .print-hidden {
    display: none;
  }
}
```